# How to get Spark in Java working - Could not initialize class org.apache.spark.util.Utils$

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am attempting to connect to a standalone spark server from a java application using the following code

```
SparkConf sparkConf_new = new SparkConf()
    .setAppName("Example Spark App")
    .setMaster("spark://my.server.com:7077");
JavaSparkContext sparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf_new);
JavaRDD<String> stringJavaRDD = sparkContext.textFile("hdfs://cluster/my/path/test.csv");
out.println("Number of lines in file = " + stringJavaRDD.count());
```

I am receiving the following error

```
An exception occurred at line 12

12: SparkConf sparkConf_new = new SparkConf()
13:     .setAppName("Example Spark App")
14:     .setMaster("spark://my.server.com:7077");
15: JavaSparkContext sparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf_new);
16: JavaRDD<String> stringJavaRDD = sparkContext.textFile("hdfs://cluster/my/path/test.csv");
17: out.println("Number of lines in file = " + stringJavaRDD.count());

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.spark.util.Utils$
    at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.<init>(SparkConf.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.<init>(SparkConf.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:54)
```

Included are:

```
scala-library-2.10.5.jar
spark-core_2.10-1.6.0.jar
hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar
```

Comment: which version of spark and hadoop are you using?

Comment: You're missing the original cause of your exception, which should be a previous `ExceptionIninitializerError` for the `Util$` class.

Comment: that is the reasson I'm here; no where in my logs does that exist which is why I've asked, normally I would see this.

@Nirmal Ram backend Spark 1.6.0 and Hadoop 2.7

Comment: Just noticed the hadoop core version updated that to 1.2.1 same issue though

Comment: On the server you are connecting to can you open the [spark-shell](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html) successfully?

Answer (score 1):

You typically package your application into an Uber JAR file and use [$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html) script to send it to the server for execution.

If you can try creating the most simple applicaiton to start with, using Maven all you should need in your project dependencies is

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Doing it this way all of your environmental config (server url, etc) can be defined out side of your Java code in a script making it more portable.

Answer (score 0):

If you write application in spark, even if you are sending it to remote cluster the three jars are not enough. You should add all spark dependencies to the classpath of the application.

The easiest way is to use maven or gradle (see http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.3/programming-guide.html#linking-with-spark) which will include spark and all its transitive dependencies.
If you cannot use build system, download an official spark build and add all jars in `jars/` directory to the classpath of your application.

Comment: Plus hadoop core should be replaced with hadoop common jar